# Resetting to defaultValues of a React-Select child component from the parent component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, react-select

I have this parent component (Membership) which contains a child component (AboutYou). The parent component does the form submission using a button. Clicking the button will also trigger a reset.

Inside the AboutYou child component is a React-Select input. I have no problem resetting all other inputs except the React-Select one. I tried to solve by doing the ff:

1. Add a defaultValue to the Controller of the react-select input
2. Add a defaultValues variable in the parent component and placing it as a parameter for the reset method

I have tried to check other examples but there are no situation for a child select-react component.

```
export default function Membership() {
    const methods = useForm<FormData>({ mode: "all" });
    const { handleSubmit, formState, reset } = methods;
    const provincesList = useProvinces();

    const onChange = (value: any) => {
        setRecaptchaSolved(true);
    };

    const defaultValues = {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        mobileNumber: "",
        dateOfBirth: "",
        city: "",
        province: "",
    };

    const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
        console.log(data);
        reset(defaultValues);
    };

    return (
        <FormProvider {...methods}>
            <div className="m-5">
                <div className="border border-gray-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg p-6 mx-auto w-full max-w-md">
                    <h1 className="text-2xl text-center mb-5">
                        <span className="font-bold">Business Club, Inc </span>
                        <br /> Membership
                    </h1>
                    <hr className="mb-5" />
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                        <AboutYou provincesList={provincesList} />
                        <button
                            className={`px-4 py-2 bg-filCebColor w-full rounded cursor-pointer inline-block
                            ${
                                !formState.isValid


                                    ? "pointer-events-none bg-slate-500 opacity-50"
                                    : ""
                            }`}
                            type="submit"
                        >
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </FormProvider>
    );
}
```

```
const AboutYou: React.FC<AboutYouProps> = ({ provincesList }) => {
    const { register, control } = useFormContext();
    const maxDate = getMaxDate();

    return (
        <div>
            //other inputs

            <label htmlFor="province" className="block mb-2">
                Province<span className="text-red-400">*</span>
            </label>
            <Controller
                name="province"
                control={control}
                defaultValue=""
                render={({ field }) => (
                    <Select
                        id="province"
                        options={provincesList}
                        onChange={(option) => option && field.onChange(option.label)}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default AboutYou;
```

Comment: I believe the React-Select component has a `value` prop, you may be able to pass in `value` from `field` depending on what props are made available in the `render` prop on `Controller`

Answer (score 1):

To reset the React-Select input along with other form inputs, you need to handle the reset logic in the child component too.
Update the child component to accept a reset prop. you can use the useEffect hook to watch for changes in the reset prop and reset the React-Select value accordingly. Try something like this,

```
const { register, control, setValue } = useFormContext()
// Watch for changes in the reset prop and reset the React-Select value 
useEffect(() => {
  setValue("province", "") 
}, [reset, setValue])
```